# V8 order of instantiating the variables (multi-thread)

Tags: c++, v8, cvv8

I'm new with Google's V8 and I'm not sure how to fully use the variable types they give. I'll start by explaining what i wish to flow to be:

1. In the main thread I want to compile the JS scripts.
2. In several threads I want to run scripts when I "add" to the context different information using instance->SetAccessor(...) or prototype->Set(...) (or any other option if there is.

I am not sure when I need to do the following:

- where and when to create the `v8::handleScope`? is creating one in the main thread is enough? or I need one for each thread?
- where and when to create `v8::isolate` and `v8::locker`? should it be per thread or not? should it be before or after the `v8::handleScope`?

Any info will help (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run the scripts in parallel from each thread with no cross-thread sharing, then each thread needs its own isolate.  You may or may not actually need one for the main thread, or you could maybe use the default isolate.  I'd recommend making sure that the default isolate has been initialized before running any threads though, just in case one of your other threads ends up initializing it.  You should be ok if you are using isolates but it won't do any harm to be sure.

If you need cross-thread sharing of objects etc then you'll need to research this and it is likely to be difficult.  Not even sure if v8 can really support it yet or not.  Having separate isolates and avoiding sharing of objects is much easier.

You should be able to compile your scripts in the context of an isolate intended for the thread that is going to execute it in the main thread and then pass the script and the isolate to the thread and not touch either again in the main thread until the worker thread is done with it.  This ought to work, but I've not checked if v8 checks the thread-id that the isolate was created in and the one it executes in.  It's worth writing a little test app to check that this will work.

The other option is to check the compilation in the main thread and compile it again in the worker thread and encapsulate the isolate in the thread.  This is the way I have done it in the past.  It's easier but less efficient.

The handle scope should be allocated on the stack only in the functions where it is needed. Don't use a global variable for the handle scope or allocate it on the heap.
Your compiled script should use a persistent handle.
Enter the handle scope after you have entered the isolate scope.

Comment: one question regarding your answer: you are saying `Your compiled script should use a persistent handle` but the `v8::Script::New` returns a Local handle. how can I compile a script and hold it in a persistent handle?